# prisma connectOrCreate create duplicates or return error

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm trying to seed a bunch of records, on a table that has a many-to-many relationships with another table.

```
model Resume {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  company     String? 
  logo        String?
  description String?
  startDate   DateTime?
  endDate     DateTime?
  createdAt   DateTime? @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt   DateTime? @map("updated_at")
  deletedAt   DateTime? @map("deleted_at")
  tags        ResumeTag[]

  @@map("resume")
}

model ResumeTag {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String    @unique
  resume      Resume[]

  @@map("resume_tags")
}
```

on script this is what i use using `connectOrCreate` ( removed other parts, but this is the gist of it):

```
const resumeSingle = {
    id: 1,
    company: 'Company A',
    name: 'Software Developer',
    logo: 'Logo.svg',
    description: '',
    startDate: moment('2016-06-01').toISOString(),
    endDate: null,
    tags: ['Node.JS', 'GraphQL', 'PostgreSQL']
  };
const { tags, ...resumeData} = resumeSingle;

await prisma.resume.create({
 data: {
  ...resumeData,
   tags: {
    connectOrCreate: tags.map(tag => ({
      where: { name: tag }, create:  { name: tag } 
    }))
   },
  },
 });
```

I have several records to insert, some with same repeated `tags`. However the code only stops with error when a new records has a tag already in the db.

```
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `name`.
```

If I remove the `unique` on `name` column in `ResumeTag` it just add duplicated in the db table (with the same name).

I'm using `connectOrCreate` wrong here?

Comment: From the requirements, are you allowed to include duplicates? Your usage of connectOrCreate appears to be correct.

Comment: No, there should be no duplicates, thats why the `@unique` on the name. But i still get the error there. only wait to make it work is to allow duplicates, but is not what i want.

Comment: Can you add `update: {}` just after `create:  { name: tag }` and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Should use `prisma.$transaction()` to avoid `Unique constraint failed on the constraint` error

```
    const resumeSingle = {
        id: 1,
        company: 'Company A',
        name: 'Software Developer',
        logo: 'Logo.svg',
        description: '',
        startDate: moment('2016-06-01').toISOString(),
        endDate: null,
        tags: ['Node.JS', 'GraphQL', 'PostgreSQL']
      };
    const { tags, ...resumeData} = resumeSingle;
    
    // remove await here
    const dbTask = prisma.resume.create({
     data: {
      ...resumeData,
       tags: {
        connectOrCreate: tags.map(tag => ({
          where: { name: tag }, create:  { name: tag } 
        }))
       },
      },
     });

     //The solution here
     const resume  = await prisma.$transaction([...dbTask])
```